# PyAudio working in Idle, but not working in PyCharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm, pyaudio

I am trying to install the PyAudio package, as described in this link: https://realpython.com/python-speech-recognition/#working-with-microphones.

I went to this site to install PyAudio: [https://lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/](https://lfd.uci.edu/%7Egohlke/pythonlibs/). I installed PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl

Then, to install PyAudio, I used the command

`pip install PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`, which installed the module successfully.

Basically, I followed this video to do so: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-AzGZ_CHzJk

Then, I tried using Idle, which worked successfully (basically, "Microphone" requires the PyAudio package, so if the "mic = sr.Microphone" worked successfully, then PyAudio was installed correctly).

[image]

However, when I try writing the exact same code in PyCharm, I get this error:

```
AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation
```

I am running Windows 10 with Python 3.8.
I put pyaudio.py into `C:\Users\myName\PycharmProjects\Virtual_Assistant_Test_1\venv\Lib\site-packages.`

**How do I import PyAudio into PyCharm?**

Comment: PyCharm may use own Python and it has not installed PyAudio. You would know path to Python used in PyCharm to use this Python to install it. OR PyCharm in settings should have information about used Python and there should be function to install modules for this Python

Comment: BTW: did you have problem to install normally `pip install PyAudio` without downloading it ?

Comment: PyCharm doc: [Install, uninstall, and upgrade packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: I could not use pip install PyAudio. Something seems to be broken about PyAudio.

Comment: I followed the link that you gave me, but when I tried running the code, this error popped up: AttributeError: Could not find PyAudio; check installation

Comment: PyCharm may have many Python on list. Did you install it for correct Python - this one which you use in your project. (or install with all of them - every Python need own installation) Did it install without errors?

Comment: How do install PyAudio for a specific Python? I also don't think there's any other Python on my computer.

Comment: What do you see in PyCharm settings - Interpreters ? Is there more Pythons on the list "Project Interpreter" ? If there are other Pythons then you have to select one by one and install for every Python separatelly.

Comment: BTW: in your project you can use `import sys` and `print(sys.executable)` to see path to `/path/to/python.exe` used by project and then you can use this path to install modules - `/path/to/python.exe -m pip install PyAudio` or `/path/to/python.exe -m pip install /path/to/PyAudio‑0.2.11‑cp38‑cp38‑win_amd64.whl`

Comment: Actually, I solved the issue. I think there was some issue with my Python installation, but I fixed it. Thank you though.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the left top side click **"File" "Settings"** then navigate to **project:"yourProjectName"** then **Python Interpreter** click on the Plus on the right side and search for PyAudio